# Syntax error when trying to test for empty string

Tags: javascript, string

In Javascript, I am trying to do a simple task of testing and returning the longest of two words. If the words are empty then the return should say "empty string". I keep getting a syntax error when testing for an empty string with the or elseif statement. I am using (!word1) and (!word2) because my understanding is in Javascript it is a boolean statement and should be false. Please tell me where I am going wrong:

```
function longest(word1, word2) {

if (word1.length >= word2.length) {

    return (word1);

} else {

    return (word2);

} else if (!word1) || (!word2) {

    return "an empty string";

}

}

console.log(longest('hi'));
```

Comment: An `else if` can't follow an `else` in the same group and `if` requires a set of parenthesis around the entire condition. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

Comment: Why are there parentheses around the values being returned?

Comment: off-topic: `else if (!word1) || (!word2)`, with an appropriate syntax, should be the 1st conditions. Usually you first check that things exists, then do logic on them

Comment: `a || b ? a.length >= b.length ? a : b : "empty string"`

Answer (score 2):

`if` conditions should be surrounded by exactly 1 pair of parentheses.

Change `else if (!word1) || (!word2)` to `else if (!word1 || !word2)`.

Comment: Still going to be a syntax error about unexpected "else"

Comment: Yep, but other answerers have already covered that, and I'd just as soon help the OP out and then close/delete this crap question.

Answer (score 0):

You got your else and else if around the wrong way. Heres the complete code for your problem.

```
function longest(word1, word2) {
if ((!word1) || (!word2)) {


    alert ("an empty string");

} else if (word1.length >= word2.length) {

    alert (word1);

}else{

   alert (word2);        

}

}

longest('hi');
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "else" clause should be the last clause in your if statement:

```
function longest(word1, word2) {

if (word1.length >= word2.length) {

    return (word1);

 } else if (!word1 || !word2) {

    return "an empty string";

} else {

    return (word2);



}

console.log(longest('hi'));
```